# Django. Cannot upload Image in models

Tags: django, django-models

I am doing Online School project. When i want to add a new language in the Teacher, image of this languages gets null. I got the similar code, but in Admin Page(not default admin). And code in Admin page is working and successfull uploading image for Language. So, i have question, why it is not uploading

My views.

```
@user_passes_test(is_teacher)
def teacher_add_language_view(request):
    languageForm=LanguageForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        languageForm=LanguageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if languageForm.is_valid():
            language=languageForm.save(commit=False)    
            author = TMODELS.Teacher.objects.get(user__username=request.user)
            language.author = author
            languageForm.save()
        else:
            print("you got error")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('teacher-languages')
    return render(request,'teacher/teacher_add_language.html',{'languages':languageForm})
```

My forms

```
class LanguageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=QMODEL.Language
        fields=['title', 'image']
```

Language model

```
class Language(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Язык'
        verbose_name_plural='Языки'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, 
                        verbose_name='Язык')
    author = models.ForeignKey(Teacher,
                            on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True,
                            blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='None', editable = False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='main_menu_picture/', 
                            null=True, blank=True)
```

it gets null? Can you help? Thanks for your att

Update:
That is Admin view creating language code, It is placed in another folder/application

```
@login_required(login_url='adminlogin')
@user_passes_test(is_admin)
def admin_add_language_view(request):
    languageForm=forms.LanguageForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        languageForm=forms.LanguageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if languageForm.is_valid():
            language=languageForm.save(commit=False)    
         
            author=TMODEL.Teacher.objects.get(
                id=request.POST.get('authorID'))
            language.author = author
            languageForm.save()
        else:
            print("form is invalid")
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin-view-language')
    return
```

render(request,'exam/admin_add_language.html'{'languages':languageForm})

UPDATE:
HTML fle for teacher_add_languages

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="off" style="margin:100px;margin-top: 0px;">
{%csrf_token%}
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="course_name">Title</label>
  {% render_field languages.title class="form-control" placeholder="Example: Databases" %}
  <label for="languageID">Author</label>
  {% render_field languages.author class="form-control" placeholder="Author" %}
  <label for="question_number">Image</label>
  {% render_field languages.image class="form-control" %}
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="border-radius: 0%;">Submit Info</button>
```

I am using widget_tweak.

Comment: You mentioned you have similar code which is working, can you show that?

Comment: can you show the html file

Comment: Try adding `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute to the form.